# UDP re-bind / reset a socket

Tags: linux, networking, udp, setsockopt

After creating and binding to a UDP socket, I'd like to later call `setsockopt` for `SO_MAX_PACING_RATE`.

What I tried to do:

- Attempt #1: I tried simply running `setsockopt` after the `bind` call, but this seems to silently fail
- Attempt #2: My next idea was to call `close` and then `bind` on the socket fd. But that didn't work because the socket is no longer bindable after the `close`.
- Attempt #3: Call `close`, then create a new socket, then call `bind` on that. Oddly, it says that the socket is still "bound".
- Attempt #4: Call `close`, wait 100ms, then create a new socket, then call `bind` on that. **This works.** What's going on here?
- Attempt #5: Also use `SO_REUSEADDR` => **This works as well.**

So my question is -- what is the canonical way create a UDP socket at a particular port, then close that socket and bind a new UDP socket on that same port?

Comment: For **1** what is your return value from `setsockopt()`? **2** Once you close, the socket isn't valid. **3** Calling close, the kernel doesn't "finish" closing before your call exists. Think of it as adding to a kernel todo list, no need to keep you waiting. **4** See my reply to 3 <-. **5** Works, but that asks kernel to duplicate it to all listeners (new and pending close one).

Comment: I'll answer once I get a reply to #1.

Comment: I'm prettty sure it returned zero. That is, no errors. My follow up question -- what documentation/code agrees with this async nature you describe? That's quite curious to me!

Comment: Two examples off the top of my head: sendfile returns before the file is transferred **and** bhyve vm create/destroy returns before the vm operation is done.

Comment: Ok if zero. Can you code that I can reproduce the error?

Comment: Here you go -- usage is in the comments at the top: https://gist.github.com/theicfire/bd0f490df2442d90741b8b75f40edaaf